# How to replace local urls of "file_get_contents" page;

Tags: javascript, php, html, telegram

Because of restrictions when using `iframe`s to load telegram pages I am using the following code:

`file_get_contents('https://t.me/s/telegram');`

But telegram loads some javascript files and makes POST queries to local files which do not exist on my server. For example, Google console shows the following as not found:

```
jquery.min.js:4 **POST https://example.com/v/ 404
jquery.min.js:4 POST https://example.com/s/telegram?before=93 404
```

You can [see it in this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8RpHu.png).

What I want is to catch these queries and convert them to global URLs like the following:

```
POST https://telegram.org/v/
POST https://telegram.org/s/telegram?before=some_integer
```

[Here is an example URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9WZSN.png) that should be replaced with telegram's URL.

Instead of my domain, the script should use telegram's domain. Would appreciate any helps/hints.

Comment: you're question is very unclear. What are you trying to achieve? what is exactly that you're trying to do? what error are you getting? I actually played with telegram's api, with php, I'd be happy to understand

Comment: @GuyLouzon, thank you for your attention. I just wanna embed telegram channel to my website. As you know all telegram channels have web pages also which can be reached by such kind of url: t.me/s/ChannelName . And when I tried to do this with php function `file_get_contents('https://t.me/s/telegram');` it shows page with only 2-3 posts. other posts are not loading. I found that they are loading with some JS-scripts in telegram.org side. But because of php function, in my case, the page trying to load JS-scripts from my side.

Comment: Just try to execute `file_get_contents('https://t.me/s/telegram');` , and you would see what problem I'm talking. I think telegram's api is unnecessary in my situation

Comment: What's the need of scraping Telegram? They are known to have a pretty good API, and scraping their page might not be legal

Comment: @NicoHaase , but in this situation API is not compatible to my needs. And also if you look to that link i mentioned in my post, it has similar design as telegram's app. By the way, I can say that it is not illegal because of I'm not breaking the rules of "Terms of use"

Answer (score 1):

I would try loading the page using file_get_contents
Then lookup all files trying to be fetched
calling them and saving them locally, then echo the original url, now that all references are saved, something like the  code below

My code might not be perfect, but I think that this is the direction you should go in. Look at source of the telegram channel, see exactly how to find the jquery POST urls, and modify it accordingly

```
$channel = file_get_contents('https://t.me/s/telegram');
$urls = array();
$jumper = 0;
$jumper2 = 0;
$tempstr = '';
$dir = '/s/' ;

$findstr = "$.ajax: ". "\n". "url:";
while ($jumper <= strlen($channel) || 
strpos($channel, $findstr,$jumper + 1)) {
 $jumper = strpos($channel, $findstr,$jumper);
 $jumper2 = strpos($channel, ',' ,$jumper + 1);
 $urls[] = substr($channel, $jumper + 9, $jumper2 - $jumper + 10);
}

foreach ($urls as $url) {
 file_put_contents($dir . $url);
}

echo $channel;
```

Comment: Refused to display 'https://t.me/s/telegram' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

Comment: I added screenshots, please, look them

Comment: Small fix. strpos must return a results different than zero. Now its ok

Comment: Sorry, but problem is still exist, infinity loading. and server responds error 503 after a while

Comment: I can't understand, I'm unlucky person or so dumb on how to execute your code.It works on your side, but in my side : still loading...

Comment: @HeadSec Good morning. I actually wrote the code like that, I didn't run it. I saw that the while condition treated the wrong search that would iterate the loop too much

Comment: My code might not be perfect, but I think that this is the direction you should go in. Look at source of the telegram channel, see exactly how to find the jquery POST urls, and nodify it accordingly

Comment: Good morning to you too. I understood. Thanks for your help. If I find something I will notice you. Thanks a lot